# How does one play Age of Empires on a Mac with steam?

Tags: mac, windows, games, steam

I was going through the following tutorial: https://youtu.be/bg8qkKXMPKA and I followed all the instructions as given but in the last step, I was not able to get Steam to work. An error pops out (which is expected):

[image]

I am supposed to just click "next" and then Steam is supposed to open. However, that does not happen. Does anyone know how to get over that? The first comment on the YouTube video says the same error as me but I can't seem to find a solution...

Comment: I would look on the playonmac website for their install instructions As for running windows I would use othe commercial version crossover or a wrapped open source version http://wineskin.urgesoftware.com/tiki-index.php

Comment: http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=247537337